# memcpy with initialized variable and negative numbers with cast

Tags: c++, c, qt, casting, memcpy

I have

```
    QByteArray bytes    // Fullfilled earlier   
    char id_c = bytes[7];   
    int _id;
    _id = 0; // If I comment this result would be different
    memcpy(&_id, &id_c, 1); 
    int result = _id;
```

I have _id variable and if I comment "_id=0" result variable result would be different with negative number. Why? Why initializing _id with 0 would be different?!
**How can I do this alternatively with same result as using "_id=0" but without memcpy and unwanted castings?**

This is not my code. I am interested how to get same result correctly without stupid castings.

Comment: you are copying a single byte onto of something thats (probably) 4 bytes. If you dont initialise the other 3 bytes then you'll get junk (technically undefined behaviour). Is there a reason you cant just do `_id = id_c;`?

Comment: I would try it and report cause I tried but forgot!

Comment: The result depends on endianess. Though I suppose portable code isn't possible anyway, since you use "cross platform" QT.

Comment: Are you planning to TX/RX `bytes` over some network?

Comment: No. I would no send them via TX/RS. I can use 
QTcpSocket and ethernet packets

Comment: @ifooi but you eventually want use the ethernet anyway. Don't you? because on a single machine nobody cares about byte ordering.

Comment: Yes. I use Ethernet anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct.

Because this statement:

```
memcpy(&_id, &id_c, 1);
```

Is only copying a single byte from `&id_c` into an address representing a 4-byte integer, `&_id`.  Only the first byte of memory occupied by `_id` gets anything copied into it.  Without the zero init of `_id` first, the remaining three bytes of that value are left undefined (presumably random garbage values off the stack).

What's wrong with an "unwanted casting"?  This is just as fine and the compiler generates the most efficient code.

```
QByteArray bytes    // Fullfilled earlier   
int _id = (int)(bytes[7]);
int result = _id;
```

If you want sign extended result of the unsigned byte copied into `_id`, then this:

```
int _id = (signed char)(bytes[7]);
```

Comment: is it better than _id=0; _id = id_c? Why it is most efficient code?

Comment: It's really hard to beat the compiler's optimizations for assigning values between variables.  `memcpy` is best for bulk copy and doing some very esoteric stuff between addresses in memory.

Comment: Also `memcpy` is useful for very explicit serialization operations from objects (structs) to and from byte arrays.  So, that might be of use if you are doing something complicated like initializing a struct from a byte array.  You could could `memcpy` each individual member of the struct to/from it's expected position in the byte array.  But in your example above, you were dealing with just a single byte, so it becomes a much easier problem.

Answer (score 2):

`_id = 0` is called assigning `0` value to the variable `_id`, if you comment that then we cannot be sure what is stored in that `_id` , and you are updating only one byte out of that, as it is of type `int` it is more than one byte in size.

Comment: This explains the cause of the problem, but actually does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: I used _id = static_cast<int>(bytes[7]) and that was wrong. I get code as it does and myabe my question is not accurate

Answer (score 1):

You might try these net/host byte order conversions:

[on linux](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl)

[on windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-htonl)

the only difference is the header file to use; You can use preprocessor tricks to determine the platform and choose the proper header if cross-platform programming is intended. A better approach is to use the C++20 feature [`std::endian`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian). But you need to handle the conversion yourself:

```
#include <bit>
#include <climits>
int int_cvt(int x){
    if constexpr (endian::native==endian::big)
       return x;
    y=0;
    while(x){
        unsigned char c=x;
        x>>=std::CHAR_BIT;
        y<<=std::CHAR_BIT;
        y+=c;
    };
    return y;
};
```

cheers,
FM.

Comment: Thanks! But there no C++2020

Comment: so you need to include proper OS dependent header.

Comment: There is QT with VS2008 IDE and compiler and attached firebird DB. I need time to reatach all .

Comment: so the windows link shall do.